# subprocess return '' (empty string) for command `docker exec`

Tags: python, docker, subprocess

`handle.stdout.read()` return '' (empty string) when the command is `sudo docker exec -it $DOCKER_ID $SHELL_COMMAND`.

```
command = 'sudo docker exec -it %s ls %s' % (docker_id, ssh_dir)
handle = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
command_out = handle.stdout.read()
```

But it can return an expected result by manually executing the command.

```
sudo docker exec -it 0b22bf73a0f5 ls /root/.ssh
authorized_keys  id_rsa
```

And if the command is`sudo docker ps | grep $FILETER_STRING`, subprocess also works.

What's the reason why `handle.stdout.read()` return ''? Thanks.

Comment: I would try `subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)` so standard _error_ is also redirected.

Comment: I tried, without getting any meaningful output, but None.

Comment: `command_out` cannot be `None`. It can be empty string. You're getting `None` or empty string?

Comment: empty, sorry and done editing the question.

Comment: can you print `command` before you're running it?

Comment: You may need to force `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL` so that `sudo` can't detect that its stdin is connected to an interactive tty: otherwise it will attempt to set `noecho` mode and prompt for a password.

Comment: Yes, its value is `sudo docker exec -it 0b22bf73a0f5 ls /root/.ssh` and the output is `authorized_keys  id_rsa` by manually executing the command.

Comment: @DanielPryden `subprocess.DEVNULL` isn't available in Python 2.7.x and I hit issue `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fileno'` when replacing `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL` with `stdin=os.devnull`. Thanks.

Comment: You can emulate `DEVNULL` by using `open(os.devnull, 'r')`. You'll just need to close the handle afterward. Or you can use a pre-exec function to `os.fclose(sys.stdin.fileno())` in the child process, to similar effect. There's also a command-line argument you can pass to `sudo` to put it in non-interactive mode, which might be the best option here.